# italic after math equation: how to solve (not solved with $)

Tags: equations, mathtools

I am not an expert with equations on latex. I have wrote these ones within a chapter of a book, but I missed how to write the label on the left with the equation number.
Moreover, the text after the equations is italic for a couples of lines and I did not find the way to fix it. 
What is wrong?

(Edit with suggestions proposed)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,  twoside, openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3.5cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small}
\usepackage{topfront}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{natbib, authoryear}
\graphicspath{figure}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

yi \in Y_{i} \sim mathrm{Multinom}(\pi^1_i , \pi^2_i , \pi^3_i ) 
\pi^k_i = \frac{exp(\eta^k_i)} {1+ \exp(\eta^2i) + exp(\eta^3i)}\hfill     k= 1,...,3

\eta^k_i = ln(\frac{\pi^k_i }{\pi^1_i}) = \beta^k_0 + x_i_1\beta^k_1 +    \sum^11_{j_=_3 } x_i_j\beta^k_j \hfill k= 2,3
\eta^1_i = 0 

some text which is italic
\end{document}
```

i have not solved the issue substituing with $\pi$

Comment: if you get a tex error then you should ask about the error message (the pdf output after any error isn't designed for use,it may possibly be useful for debugging but nothing else)

Comment: You need to start the math mode with (for example) `\[` and end it with `\]` (and remove the `\bigskip`)  also `exp` should be `\exp` and `Multinom` should be `\mathrm{Multinom}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you mean i have to add \[ and \] for each line or just once at the beginning and at the end of the equations?thank you

Comment: really you should start with a basic tutorial on latex, as there are so many errors here in so few lines... I'll post something  as an answer  too long for a comment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you, i read a lot about equations but still i was not able to solve the problem

Comment: surely _anything_ you read must have told you that math expressions need to be in a math environment `\[` or `equation` or `align` etc.

Comment: @ggg: Fundamentally your problem is solved when placing the math content in a math environment (`$`...`$`, `\[`...`\]`, `\begin{equation}`...`\end{equation}`, ...). Of course, the use of a math environment depends on what you're wanting to display and how. For example, you may need an `align` environment to stack equations on top of one another and have them aligned at some horizontal mark, but that's a different question than what you asked here...

Comment: @Werner do you mean one among the three options($...$, \[...\], \begin{equation}...\end{equation}, ... or all of them?

Comment: @ggg: One of them, but it depends on the output you're after. Each has their own place - `$`...`$` for in-line, text-style math; `\[`...`\]` for single-line display-style math without an equation number, `\begin{equation}`...`\end{equation}` for single-line display-style math with an equation number, `\begin{align}`...`\end{align}` (and others) for multi-line display-style math with/without equation numbers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

I had to take some guesses as to the intended meaning in some cases...

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,  twoside, openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator\Multinom{Multinom}

\begin{document}

some text
\begin{equation}
yi \in Y_{i} \sim \Multinom(\pi^1_i , \pi^2_i , \pi^3_i ) 
\end{equation}

some more text ${x_i}_1$ ?? $\sum^1$ ???
\begin{align}
\pi^k_i &= \frac{\exp(\eta^k_i)} {1+ \exp(\eta^2i) + \exp(\eta^3i)}  &&  k= 1,\dots,3\\
\eta^k_i &= \ln(\frac{\pi^k_i }{\pi^1_i}) = \beta^k_0 + x_{i1}\beta^k_1 +    \sum^11_{j=3 } x_{ij}\beta^k_j &&k= 2,3\\
\eta^1_i &= 0 
\end{align}

some text which is italic
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved all the issues but not the one of italic. could it be because i'm using texshop on a mac? just a couple of questions: there is a way to left align the first equation? and can i used just one numbered label for all this lines (instead of a number for each line)?

Comment: @ggg you can left align everything by using `fleqn` option on `\documentclass` and you can replace `align` by `\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}\end{equation}`  if you want a single number. If you need more help then ask a new question not comments under an existing answer, but please take some time to read the amsmath user guile (amsldoc.pdf) first, there are many examples of all these things.